# CSS background images not showing in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In IE8 and below, I'm doing this

```
<ul class="dependants_list" style="border-bottom: dashed 1px #53a1dc">

     <li class="dependants_summary">
     <strong>Name:</strong> De Silva, Angelina<br />
     <strong>Gender:</strong> Female<br />
     <strong>Date of birth:</strong> 7/3/2009<br />
    </li>
    <form action="/Dependant/Delete/11413" method="get"><input class="delete btn" id="Delete_this_Profile" name="Delete_this_Profile" type="submit" value="Delete this Profile" />
     </form><form action="/Dependant/Edit/11413" method="get"><input class="edit btn" id="Modify_this_Profile" name="Modify_this_Profile" type="submit" value="Modify this Profile" />
     </form><br /><hr style="display:none" />
```

and the CSS for it is:

```
.dependants_summary 
{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 85px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 430px;
    float: left;
    font: 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.dependants_list
{
    padding: 0;
}
.dependants_list li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #fff url("../images/dependant_male.png") no-repeat scroll 8px 9px;
}
.dependants_list li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #c9e3f4 url("../images/dependant_male.png") no-repeat scroll 8px 9px;
}
```

The images are not being shown in IE, but they are in ffox and chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nth-child is [not supported at all](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) in Internet Explorer.

I think you won't get around numbering the elements manually (i.e. adding classes to them that specify the correct colouring.)

Comment: Someone should send that table to MS and ask why they're so slow.

Comment: To be fair, other browsers have trouble with this selector too, and MS have it in IE9.

Comment: That's true, I was commenting on the amount of red blocks under the MS name in that table :)

Answer (score 3):

nth-child selectors arent supported by IE unfortunately